# converting sql query to rails 2.3.5 compatible

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

below is my sql query

```
SELECT individuals.* FROM ( select children.*  FROM checkins, children WHERE 
checkins.child_id = children.id AND checkins.event_id = 1234 ) temp, 
individuals WHERE temp.individual_id = individuals.id 
ORDER BY individuals.firstname;
```

can some convert this to rails 2.3.5 compatible (active record find method)

[edited]

```
SELECT individuals.* FROM ( SELECT children.*  
FROM checkins INNER JOIN children 
ON checkins.child_id = children.id WHERE checkins.event_id = 1234 ) temp 
INNER JOIN individuals ON temp.individual_id = individuals.id ORDER BY
individuals.firstname;
```

Comment: Suggest rewritting you're SQL query to use JOINS and then use Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Individual.find(:all, :joins => {:children => :checkins}, :conditions => 'checkins.event_id = 1234', :order => 'individuals.firstname')
```

Comment: `{:children => : checkins}` => `{:child => : checkins}`